# How to get the last month year and now month year in sql

Tags: sql

I have list of data in datetime = 2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 
I want to query the list of data from Dec 2015 to May 2016. Any idea ? thanks

Comment: I think your a missing some info mate.

Comment: Tag the dbms used, time/date is one of the worst areas when in comes to ANSI SQL compliance...

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
where field >= '2015-12-01' 
and field < '2016-06-01'
```

Comment: @craig: Looking at my profile you can see that I know how to format a post. And I like the way I format my posts. If you think your programming style is better then you are welcome to format your own posts accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you do have a lot of points but that doesn't mean you are perfect. There is no need to take an edit personal. IMO the edit improved the readability of your answer which is the end goal. Here is a post discussing when to make edits http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code. Great job on all your contributions!

Comment: I know the when-to-edit post and I still would decline your edit as "no improvement whatsoever". :) There are just so many useless edits these days.... but anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: All good...this isn't the the first time I've heard of developers disagreeing on a subject ;) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Do the necessory changes.It will work.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE 
    DateField BETWEEN '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000' and '2016-06-31 23:59:59.999'
```